# java multiple string array compare

Tags: java, arrays, compare

I have 9 string arrays that I've read from file. One of the array(main) is going to be compared to the other arrays respectively. The arrays have different length.
I write a match function that checks each news item equals to the other array items. If match occurs then write the label of the array. If match is not done then "/o" is printed.
The problem is i have eight functions for each array and i want to decrease the complexity and do it in one function. How could i achieve it? My sample code is :
The sample is only for arr1, so I need to write it 7 times for the other arrays.

```
String[] main = "g, a1, c1, r,..."
String[] arr1 = "a1, b1, c1"
String[] arr2 = "e, r, g" 
String[] arr3 = "g, m, l, x"
String[] arr4 = "s, b, l"
String[] arr5 = "a, f, o, t, e"
String[] arr5 = "g, h, j"
String[] arr5 = "q, b"
String[] arr5 = "z, v, n"


for (int j = 0; j < main.length; j++) { 
   for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
   int varLength = arr1[i].length();
   for (int e = 3; e < varLength; e++) {  // substring is done by 3 
           String substr1 = arr1[i].substring(0, e)
          if (substr1.equalsIgnoreCase(main[j]))   
             {
    main[j] = main[j] + "/arr1";
             }
       }
   }
}


Expected Output : 
arr1 = "g/O, a1/arr1, c1/arr1, r/O"
arr2 = "e/O, r/arr2, g/arr2 "
arr3 = "g/arr3, m/O, l/O, x/O"  And goes like this for the other arrays
```

Comment: I don't really get what you want to do, but if I understand correctly you want to select the array that contains the same item as your main array from the other arrays? This case check their length first (if the length doesn't match the content wont either) then iterate through either and check if all elements are equal respectivelly. Or just use Sets this is what they're made for. Also your for loop for e is just appends the same string 3 times which don't seem to make sense, also your str1 is undefined. It's very hard to answer your question, please try to make it clearer

Comment: I have editted the question, str1 is the result of substring method. The arrays have mostly different values. The main array is compared to each of them. Then the result with the matched words is printed.

Comment: How can I implement with sets ?

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't get the question, would you mind adding expected output?

Comment: I have editted the question with the expected solution

Comment: The way in which you define your string arrays is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop on all the arrays:

```
// Create an array containing your 7 arrays
String[][] allArrays = new String[][] {arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5, arr6, arr7};
int counter = 1;
for(String[] arr : allArrays) {
    for (int j = 0; j < main.length; j++) { 
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            // do as before
            main[j] = main[j] + "/arr" + counter++;
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: since you need the array index (you've called it "counter"), you might as well use a regular for-each of `k=0..8` and `allArrays[k]`

Comment: I could. It does not change anything.

Comment: how could each array printed individually when we loop all the arrays ?

Comment: I have this kind of code @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan, I want to decrease the comlexity. I asked for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve is this,

```
  public static matcher(String[] main, String[] toMatch, String arrayName) {
    for(String curr : main) {
        String toAppend = "/0";
        for(String matchAgains : toMatch) {
            for (int e = 3; e < varLength; e++) {  // substring is done by 3 
               String substr1 = curr.substring(0, e)    
               if(substr1.equalsIgnoreCase(matchAgainst)) {
                    toAppend = arrayName;
               }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(main+"/"+toAppend);
    }
}
```

use a function like this which you could call like `matcher(main,arr1,"arr1");` otherwise if you'd be looking for full matches (not just the substring) you could use sets, where you could do (that was my initial thought, but I misunderstood the question)

```
public static matcher(Set<String> main, Set<String> toMatch, String arrayName) {
    for(String curr : main) {
        String toAppend = "/0";
        if(toMatch.contains(main)) {
            toAppend=arrayName;
        }

        System.out.println(main+"/"+arrayName);
    }
}
```